# VB.net - Open solution by dates of saving

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Is there any possibility to load a solution in Visual Studio (Visual Basic) which is not last saved?

I made a mistake and pasted 500 000 rows in code, and VB is not loading properly because of that large amount of data. But it remained saved, and if I reload a solution, it still keeps that amount of data.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where did you paste this "rows"? If you want to remove them just locate the file involved, open it in a TEXT editor and remove the rows.

Comment: Depending on OS and setup you could use _Previous Versions_. Have a look at [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/56891/use-windows-7s-previous-versions-to-go-back-in-time-and-save-your-files/)

Comment: This might be better suited on SuperUser